# Running Multiple Websites on The same Server with Multiple IPv4

Tags: html, apache, debian

From what I understand since that I have a server with 29 usable IPs, that means I should be able to make multiple websites on the same machine with a different IP.

My only question is how to do this, I've looked around but it all seems to be just people trying to find out how to do it if they only have one IP. But I have a server running Apache2 and 29 IPS

Comment: what OS are you running? how many NIC cards are on the server? What is the memory and disk space of the server? and last of all what is your NIC uplink bandwidth?

Comment: I'm running debian. I'm not sure about the NIC cards I'm renting from a server hosting company and all I know is that I have and Ip with 29 IPs. Bandwidth is 1Gbit. Memory I've got 8 gb of ram and 1tb HD space.

Comment: Who is the datacenter, OVH?

Comment: do you have SSH to the server?

Comment: Yes I have full SSH. I have a dedicated machine root and everything. I just am new to Apache and don't know how to use it. Its probably a simple thing I just can't find any information on it.

Comment: No Problem, do you have any hosting software on the server?

Comment: also do you know if your ip addresses are in a vlan?

Comment: I don't know the answer to either of those questions.

Comment: can you send me a link to the server you leased from the sales page

Comment: https://www.datashack.net/cart/?id=151

Comment: so you did not purchase a control panel correct. and according to the link you sent me you have a /29 block of IP's. that gives you 5 usable IP addresses.

Comment: I did not purchase a pannel no and I screwed up on the usable IPs, it is 5, you are correct.

Comment: do you plan on running your DNS from this box?

Comment: I guess, I already am running one web server on this server, at Agoria.ca (http://107.150.40.114/) I just want to be able to get another one setup with a different ip such as 107.150.40.115, if I understand how this works correctly

Comment: That is your site? im putting together info for you now.

Comment: Thats the current site I am running on the server and I wish to be running more.

Comment: Let me know how you make out.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is see if the IP addresses are set up on the NIC interfaces, Type ifconfig in the command line from SSH and look for interfaces with your IP addresses, if there is only one public you need to do the following.

In SSH type `cd /etc/network/interfaces`
then type `ls -l`

You will see a list of interfaces like below:

`eth0` is what you are looking for, And look to see if you have `eth0:0`  `eth0:1` `eth0:2` if you do not have the other eth interfaces do the following.

Let’s assume that we want to create four additional virtual interfaces to bind 4 IP addresses (172.16.16.126, 172.16.16.127, 172.16.16.128, 172.16.16.129 ,and 172.16.16.130) to the NIC.

Type `cd /etc/network/interfaces`

Now open “eth0” file and add “IPADDR_START” and “IPADDR_END” IP address range as shown below.

Type `vi eth0`

This /etc/network/interfaces text assigns three IP addresses to eth0.

```
    auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.42
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

    auto eth0:0
    allow-hotplug eth0:0
    iface eth0:0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.43
    netmask 255.255.255.0

    auto eth0:1
    allow-hotplug eth0:1
    iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.44
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

An alias interface should not have "gateway" or "dns-nameservers"; dynamic IP assignment is permissible.

The above configuration is the previous traditional method that reflects the traditional use of ifconfig to configure network devices. ifconfig has introduced the concept of aliased or virtual interfaces. Those types of virtual interfaces have names of the form interface:integer and ifconfig treats them very similarly to real interfaces.

Save it and restart/start network service

Type `service network restart`

Verify that virtual interfaces are created with IP Address.

Type  `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:FD:4C
          inet addr:172.16.16.125  Bcast:172.16.16.100  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe28:fd4c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:127317 (124.3 KiB)  TX bytes:200787 (196.0 KiB)
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000

eth0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:FD:4C
          inet addr:172.16.16.126  Bcast:172.16.16.100  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:FD:4C
          inet addr:172.16.16.127  Bcast:172.16.16.100  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:FD:4C
          inet addr:172.16.16.128  Bcast:172.16.16.100  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000

eth0:3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:FD:4C
          inet addr:172.16.16.129  Bcast:172.16.16.100  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000

eth0:4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:28:FD:4C
          inet addr:172.16.16.130  Bcast:172.16.16.100  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:18 Base address:0x2000
```

For HTTP:

To set up Name based virtual hosting you must need to tell Apache to which IP you will be using to receive the Apache requests for all the websites or domain names. We can do this with NameVirtualHost directive. Open Apache main configuration file with VI editor.

Type `vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Search for NameVirtualHost and uncomment this line by removing the # sign in front of it.

NameVirtualHost
Next add the IP with possible in which you want to receive Apache requests. After the changes, your file should look like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.100:80
```

Now, it’s time to setup Virtual host sections for your domains, move to the bottom of the file by pressing Shift + G. Here in this example, We are setting up virtual host sections for two domains

www.example1.com
www.example2.com

Add the following virtual directives at the bottom of the file for each site and ip address you have below list 2 samples.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.100:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example1.com
    ServerName www.example1.com
ErrorLog logs/www.example1.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/www.example1.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2.com
    ServerName www.example2.com
ErrorLog logs/www.example2.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/www.example2.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

You are free to add as many directives you want to add in your domains virtual host section. When you are done with changes in httpd.conf file, please check the syntax of files with following command.

type `httpd -t`

```
Syntax OK
```

It is recommended to check the syntax of the file after making some changes and before restarting the Web server because if any syntax goes wrong Apache will refuse to work with some errors and eventually affect your existing web server go down for a while. If syntax is OK. Please restart your Web server and add it to chkconfig to make your web server start in runlevel 3 and 5 at the boot time only.

Type `service httpd restart`

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Comment: The location /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ doesn't exist. /etc/sysconfig/ doesn't even exist, I am running Debian and think it's different.

Comment: Sorry so used to CentOS, Use "/etc/network/interfaces"

Comment: Having a bit of an issue with it, not sure excatly what to put in the file. I posted this: http://serverfault.com/questions/724699/setting-up-usable-ips-on-debian